# glossy reflection in ray tracing

Tags: graphics, raytracing

I am doing a project about ray tracing, right now I can do some basic rendering.

The image below have:

mirror reflection,
refraction,
texture mapping 
and shadow.

[image]

I am trying to do the glossy reflection, so far this is what I am getting.
Could anyone tell me if there is any problem in this glossy reflection image?

[image]

In comparison, the image below is from the mirror reflection

[image]

This is my code about glossy reflection, basically, once a primary ray intersect with an object.
From this intersection, it will randomly shot another 80 rays, and take the average of this 80 rays color. The problem I am having with this code is the magnitude of x and y, I have to divide them by some value, in this case 16, such that the glossy reflect ray wouldn't be too random. Is there anything wrong with this logic?

```
             Colour c(0, 0, 0);

                     for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {

                          Ray3D testRay;
                          double a = rand() / (double) RAND_MAX;
                          double b = rand() / (double) RAND_MAX;
                          double theta = acos(pow((1 - a), ray.intersection.mat->reflectivity));
                          double phi = 2 * M_PI * b;
                          double x = sin(phi) * cos(theta)/16;
                          double y = sin(phi) * sin(theta)/16;
                          double z = cos(phi);
                          Vector3D u = reflect.dir.cross(ray.intersection.normal);
                          Vector3D v = reflect.dir.cross(u);
                          testRay.dir = x  * u + y * v  + reflect.dir;
                          testRay.dir.normalize();

                          testRay.origin = reflect.origin;
                          testRay.nbounces = reflect.nbounces;
                          c = c + (ray.intersection.mat->reflectivity)*shadeRay(testRay);
                     }
                     col = col + c / 80;
```

Comment: a and b will have a random value between 0 and 1

Comment: FWIW, I don't think your code is entirely correct - the glossy reflection of the green ellipsoid should be symmetrical about the view axis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from the hard coded constants which are never great when coding, there is a more subtle issue, although your images overall look good.

Monte-Carlo integration consists in summing the integrand *divided by the probability density function* (pdf) that generated these samples. There are thus two problems in your code:

- you haven't divided by the pdf although you seem to have used a pdf for Phong models (if I recognized it well ; at least it is not a uniform pdf)
- you have further scaled your `x` and `y` components by `1./16.` for apparently no reason which further changes your pdf.

The idea is that *if you are able to sample your rays exactly according to Phong's model times the cosine law* then you don't even have to multiply your integrand by the BRDF. In practice, there are no exact formula that allow to sample exactly a BRDF (apart from Lambertian ones), so you need to compute:
`pixel value = sum BRDF*cosine*incoming_light / pdf`
which mostly cancels out if `BRDF*cosine = pdf`.

Of course, your images overall look good, so if you're not interested in physical plausibility, that may as well be good.
A good source about the various pdfs used in computer graphics and Monte-Carlo integration (with the appropriate formulas) is the [Global Illumination Compendium](http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~philip.dutre/GI/TotalCompendium.pdf) by Philip Dutré.